Set JSON array as variable for json.dumps
I'm searching for a way to read a specific value of multiple JSON arrays.
I was able to count them and now want to get a specific value from each of them but I wasn't able to find a way to set [0], [1], [2], etc. as a variable.
LineCount = len(obj['data']['monitors']);

print ("Active Lines:", LineCount)

LineNb = "obj['data']['monitors'][" + LineCount + "]['lines'][0]['name']"

LineName = json.dumps(LineNb)
        
print (LineCount, "Line", LineName)

while LineCount > 1:
    LineCount -= 1
    LineNb = "obj['data']['monitors'][" + LineCount + "]['lines'][0]['name']"
    print (LineCount, "Line", LineName)


A Json string is not a database where you can access arbitrary elements. If you want ho save selected elements then select them in Python and then dumps them to a string. Or use a nonSQL database that works on Json structures.

Don't put it in a string. Just use LineName = obj['data']['monitors'][LineCount]['lines'][0]['name']

Yeah, the way you're doing it is incorrect. Rather than trying to access a string, use a JSON object as suggested. Putting it in a string has no purpose here, unless you're doing something like eval, which again begs the question - why?

If you want to iterate over the items in obj['data']['monitors'], then ... just do that.  What is the difficulty?

Though not recommended, a quick fix is to eval the string:
LineNb = "obj['data']['monitors'][" + LineCount + "]['lines'][0]['name']"
LineNb = eval(LineNb)

...

Alternatively, I recommend just removing the quotes, to turn it from str into accessing the JSON object obj directly:

LineNb = obj['data']['monitors'][LineCount]['lines'][0]['name']

...

